# Can we use path values in <path path="..."> in page-flow.xml without wildcards?

Tags: orbeon

I have a sample application `hello-world` with two files.

#### `page-flow.xml` - with wildcard in path

```
<controller xmlns="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/controller">
    <page path="*" view="hello.xhtml"/>
</controller>
```

#### `hello.xml`

```
<html>
    <body>
    Hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

If I enter http://localhost:8080/orbeon/hello-world/hello in the browser it works as expected.

If I replace the `path` argument with a specific path value, I get an **Orbeon Forms Page - Page Not Found**, though.

#### `page-flow.xml` - without wildcard in path

```
<controller xmlns="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/controller">
    <page path="/hello" view="hello.xhtml"/>
</controller>
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path that must match is `/hello-world/hello`, not just `/hello`. So try instead:

```
<controller xmlns="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/controller">
    <page path="/hello-world/hello" view="hello.xhtml"/>
</controller>
```